# Boxes always take the full width

Tags: tex-core

How can I have a box not take the full width?

ie.

```
\hbox{keke}\hbox{lala} % end up on their own lines instead of same line.
\vbox{keke}\vbox{lala} % same thing, except also indented.
```

Why does `\hbox` by default take the whole line width? Does not compute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to exit vertical mode, otherwise TeX just stacks up the hboxes.

```
\leavevmode\hbox{keke}\hbox{lala}
```

Comment: This is precisely what LaTeX's `\mbox` does for you.